# Node.JS: Simple GET with request module throwing "Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected"

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, web-scraping, request

Was trying to understand the basics of Web Scraping & was successful doing it with Python. When trying to emulate the same with Node getting following error :

**Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 pipe listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit**

Below is simple code snippet that am trying to run using **node scrape.js** :

```
const request = require('request');

const uri = 'https://www.somewebsite.com/auth/get_menu/?city_id=1';
const headers = {
    'accept': '*/*',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'app_client': 'consumer_web'
};

process.on('warning', e => console.warn(e.stack));

request({uri, headers, method: 'GET'}, (err, response, body) => {
    if(!err){
        console.log(response);

        console.log(body);
    }
});
```

Please let me where am doing it wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the website you are trying to scrap generates infinte loop with cookies disabled, so you need to enable them when make the request. Somethink like this should work.

```
const request = require("request");

const uri = "https://www.bigbasket.com/auth/get_menu/?city_id=1";
const headers = {
  accept: "*/*",
  "content-type": "application/json",
  app_client: "consumer_web"
};

process.on("warning", e => console.warn(e.stack));

request({ uri, headers, method: "GET", "jar": true }, (err, response, body) => {
  if (!err) {
    console.log(response);

    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

setting `jar` to true is the trick here.

By the way request module is getting unmaintained so better to use some modern packages like `got`, `axios` etc. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @Ashish, will definitely have a look at ```axios```.

Comment: Ashish i did give ```axios``` library a try & having few issues. Have posted another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59851293/). Please see if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can diagnose the cause of this memory leak with this command `node --trace-warnings app.js`

By default Nodejs allow you to set 10 listeners for any single event, if you want to change the limit, you can use set `setMaxListeners`.

But before increasing the limit, make sure there is no such thing like infinite loop that is causing memory leak.