# Node.JS: Simple GET with axios module throwing "Error: Max redirects exceeded"

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, web-scraping, axios

Was trying to understand the basics of Web Scraping & was successful doing it with Python. When trying to emulate the same with Node getting following error :

**UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Max redirects exceeded.**

Below is simple code snippet that am trying to run using node scrape.js :

```
const axios = require('axios');

const url = 'https://www.somewebsite.com/auth/get_menu/?city_id=1';
const headers = {
    'accept': '*/*',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'app_client': 'consumer_web'
};

axios.get(url, {
    headers,
    maxRedirects: 0
  })
.then(resp => {
    console.log(resp.body);
})
.catch(error => {
    if (error.response) {
      console.log(error.response.data);
      console.log('---------------------------------------------');
      console.log(error.response.status);
      console.log('---------------------------------------------');
      console.log(error.response.headers);
    } else if (error.request) {
      console.log(error.request);
    } else {
      // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
      console.log('Error', error.message);
    }
    console.log(error.config);
});
```

NOTE : As pointed out in comments - the URL with those headers, does a 302 redirect to `/skip_explore/?c=1&n=/auth/get_menu/?city_id=1` which then does a redirect to `/auth/get_menu/?city_id=1` which is now a loop that lasts forever.

Please let me where am doing it wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, that URL with those headers, does a 302 redirect to `/skip_explore/?c=1&n=/auth/get_menu/?city_id=1` which then does a redirect to `/auth/get_menu/?city_id=1` which is now a loop that lasts forever. So, there's probably something wrong with your original request that doesn't work with the server.

Comment: am not exactly sure about what headers to set. Tried through one of the request libraries article in python which worked so copied it over to node sample. It worked with request node library and have posted question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59809253/)

Comment: @jfriend00 i understood what you were referring to now. I updated the code with catch block now. Well if you look my code with ```request``` library with same URL things are working fine, there's no problem with the server that am accessing.

Comment: Yes, it is apparently because of cookies.  You need a cookie jar which you can configure with axios or request.  It is a somewhat stupid server that sets a cookie, then redirects and then if the cookie isn't there causes an infinite redirect loop.  Redirects should be stateless where they just put some info in the query string of the redirected URL and then no cookie is needed. If you want to use axios, you can search for "cookie jar with axios" and see how to configure it.

Comment: Well issue got resolved with that search buddy. Thanks a ton @jfriend00. Following links helped me out : [one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-cookiejar-support) & [two](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/48)